# Is it possible to disable Magento Message Queues

Tags: magento2.3, message-queue, magento2.3.x

It seems that Magento 2.3 introduced the concept of message queues where certain jobs like bulk product updates, exports and some sales rule functionality is now processed asynchronously via these message queues, presumably for performance and scalability reasons.

Unfortunately there is a known issue that means that these message queue processes get spawned but never die resulting in endless loops that cause server crashes. see https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17951

I've never found that bulk updates, exports etc have ever had any performance impact on any of the Magento sites I have put live. I would prefer not to use these message queues and instead revert back to the functionality that existed before. Does anyone know if that is possible?